# How to add a new column based on a few other variables

Tags: r, if-statement, case-when

I am new to R and am having trouble creating a new variable using conditions from already existing variables.  I have a dataset that has a few columns: Name, Month, Binary for Gender, and Price.  I want to create a new variable, Price2, that will:

1. make the price charged 20 if [the month is 6-9(Jun-Sept) and Gender is 0]
2. make the price charged 30 if [the month is 6-9(Jun-Sept) and Gender is 1]
3. make the price charged 0 if [the month is 1-5(Jan-May) or month is 10-12(Oct-Dec]

--

```
structure(list(Name = c("ADI", "SLI", "SKL", "SNK", "SIIEL", "DJD"), Mon = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Gender = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), Price = c(23, 34, 32, 64, 23, 34)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your dataset, or provide the output of the following `dput(head(mydf))`, with `mydf` being the name of your dataframe.

Comment: structure(list(Name = c("ADI", "SLI", "SKL", "SNK", "SIIEL", 
"DJD"), Mon = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Gender = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA), Price = c(23, 34, 32, 64, 23, 34)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: The data set has 48 entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `case_when()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
mydf$newprice <- dplyr::case_when(
  mydf$Mon >= 6 & mydf$Mon <= 9 & mydf$Gender == 0 ~ 20,
  mydf$Mon >= 6 & mydf$Mon <= 9 & mydf$Gender == 1 ~ 30,
  mydf$Mon < 6 | mydf$Mon > 9 ~ 0)
```